# Embed SVG image in HTML and keep text as text

Tags: html, svg, text

Consider [an SVG image with text](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/text/toap04.svg). Is it possible to embed it into an HTML document using an `image` tag (or any other) and keep the text as text, so it can be selected or searched for e.g. using "control+find"?

A plain `image` tag does not achieve this:

```html
<image src="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/text/toap04.svg"></image>
```

Comment: In HTML, there is no such thing as `<image>`. Did you mean `<img>` and is that the source of your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options when embedding an SVG with selectable text.

### Inline SVG

You can embed an inline SVG in an HTML document using the `<svg>` tag.

```html
    <svg width="453px" height="136px" viewBox="0 0 1000 300">
  <defs>
    <path id="MyPath" d="M 100 125 
                 C 150 125 250 175 300 175
                 C 350 175 450 125 500 125
                 C 550 125 650 175 700 175
                 C 750 175 850 125 900 125" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red" />
  <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="60" fill="blue" letter-spacing="2">
    <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
      Choose shame or get war
    </textPath>
  </text>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="998" height="298" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

### `<object>` tag

You can also use the `<object>` tag when linking to an external SVG.

```html
<object data="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/text/toap04.svg" width="453" height="136"></object>
```

Comment: But you must hardcode the image within the `svg` tag, am I right? I need to link it to an external source.

Comment: @user171780 If it needs to link to an external SVG, you can also use an <object> tag to achieve this. I've updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can load any external file, **and inline it**, with the `<load-file>` (native javascript) Web Component.

Loads of options, unlicensed and only 8 lines of code:
[Dev.To blog post <load-file> Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

```html
<script src="https://load-file.github.io/element.js"></script>
 
<load-file replaceWith src="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/text/toap04.svg"></load-file>

<style>
  svg{ background:lightgreen }
  rect { stroke:green; stroke-width:60; rx:60 }
</style>
```